# Access method of interface through custom annotation in junit test method

Tags: java, annotations, junit5, annotation-processing, junit-jupiter

I want to access a method in an interface in my test class method in compile time just by using a custom annotation. I dont want to implement the interface by test class. Below are the examples of interface, custom annotation and Test class.

```
public interface A {
  default Student prepareRequest() {
        return Student.builder()
                .firstName("FirstNamee")
                .lastName("LastNamee")
                .build();
    }
}
```

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@Test
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
}
```

```
class SampleControllerTest {

@CustomAnnotation
void testAdd() {
    //prepareRequest() should be accessible here
}

}
```

I learnt about @Aspect, BeanPostProcessing and junit jupiter extensions for annotation processing and these are good concepts for runtime processing but I am not getting how can we access that method at compile time just by using custom annotation.
Need some guidance for this.

I tried implementing Junit ParameterResolver extension by a custom extension class by giving test method parameter and injecting them at runtime. That worked for me but I dont want to give parameters to the test method and access the prepareRequest() directly

Comment: In case I understand your question correctly, what you want requires a different compilation than Java‘s standard one; otherwise your call to prepareRequest() will always lead to a compilation error. Runtime annotations cannot do that, only annotation processors can. JUnit does not come with an annotation processor so you‘d have to develop one yourself. That said, I just don’t understand why you‘d want that behaviour, it seems very opaque and unintuitive to a Java developer.

Comment: I want to force anyone who would write the junit test to use the default request and response. If they want to change the request or response object then they will have to use setter method to set the fields. The purpose is only to have code for mocking, rest all other stuff like assertions should be moved to annotation processor. I have tried creating annotation processor but it would just work on runtime. Is there any way I can access and modify prepareRequest at compile time only using annotation?

Comment: Java agents are the mechanism to modify code at compile time.

Comment: @johanneslink in case you are refering to the Java Instrumentation API, it seems from [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) that it is a *runtime* plugin (loaded to the JVM), not a *compile time* plugin. At least this is my understanding by reading some resources on the topic (and a brief reading of the docs). Could you please clarify how to use agents at compile time?

Comment: Strictly speaking it’s not at compile time but you can transform the already generated byte code. An old but I still think relevant intro can be found here: https://www.infoq.com/articles/Easily-Create-Java-Agents-with-ByteBuddy/